# Insert range of numbers from BST to Linked-List

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I need to write a function that gets a node (root) of a BST (AVL for that matter), and numbers high and low. and return a Linked List of all the numbers that are inside the range low-high (including).
Note: low / high are not necessarily in the tree + there are no repetitions of a number.
For example:

[image]

Where low = 2 and high = 8  (and the node we get is 7 which is always the root of the tree)

It would return: `[3,5,8]`

I thought of finding the common node of low and high (in my example above is the node with 7 as its key), meaning I find the highest common ancestor of low & high.

Then call another function, `wrapRangeToList(AVLNode<T> common, int low, int high, LinkedList<T> rangeList)` which gets the common root, low&high and an empty linkedlist from the imported util: `import java.util.LinkedList;`  which recursively checks if the current node has a value between low and high and adds it to the empty list if it is, and does not otherwise:

```
private LinkedList<T> wraperRangeToList(AVLNode<T> common, int low, int high, LinkedList<T> rangeList) {

        if(common == null)
            return new LinkedList<T>();

        if(common.getKey() >= low && common.getKey() <= high) { // if in range (low<=key<=high)
            rangeList.add(common.getData()); // stores the data of that node.
            this.wrapperRange(common.getLeftChild(), low, high, rangeList).addAll(this.wrapperRange(common.getRightChild(), low, high, rangeList));
            return rangeList;

        }

        else if (common.getKey() < low)
            return this.wrapperRange(common.getRightChild(), low, high, rangeList);
        else
            return this.wrapperRange(common.getLeftChild(), low, high, rangeList);



    }
```

the problem is that for a simple tree it returns a massive amount of data (a very long linked list) and I can't find the mistake or any solution of this on the internet.. thank you for you help in advance!

Comment: I'm a big fan of step-wise refinement. Do you know how to traverse your tree in key order? That's basically what you need to do and then only add nodes to the linked list when the key is in range. Once you have that working you can augment with a search for the initial low node and also break out of the traversal once you're past the high node.

Comment: But what is the base if statement? What do i return? An empty array?